# X-Y representation

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have a question about plotting two functions that have a common argument, e.g. time, in a single figure, such that the values of one function are used for the x-axis and the those of the second function for the ordinary y-axis.

How can we for example specify two functions $x=f_1(t)$ & $y=f_2(t)$ such that when plotting these two functions in a single figure, a circle is created by varying the variable t?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: see parametric function

Answer (score 3):

This is called 
[parametric representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation).

For the circle you want
$$
f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t).
$$

This traces the full circle  as $t$ varies from $0$ to $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also tell me what is the proper range for the common value - here time - when plotting the x-y representation? When plotting this in MATLAB, I get an ellipse instead of a circle.

Comment: See my edits. If you're seeing an ellipse it's probably because Matlab (or your window) has different scales on the $x$ and $y$ axes.